# what is the name of that in python

Tags: python, closures, anonymous-function, lambda

I know what are closures and what are lambda functions but I want to know what is the name of that :

```
>>> def foo(a, b):
>>>     return a + b
>>>
>>> bar = foo
>>> bar(1, 1)
>>> 2
```

I just want to know the fact of bind a function in a variable

Comment: It is called a functor

Comment: @d-stroyer This is python, not category theory.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is called [first-class functions.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-class_function) Quoting Wikipedia:

> Specifically, this means the language supports passing functions as arguments to other functions, returning them as the values from other functions, and *assigning them to variables or storing them in data structures*. [emphasis is mine]

Comment: I'd avoid to simply link to wikipedia. If you add an explicit quote of the first lines the answer will be more complete.

Comment: Quoted the sentence mentioning the feature author is curious about.

Comment: Thanks this answer to my question, so anonymous functions are not first class object and closure are ?

Comment: @user2618216 In python **everything** is a first class object. Classes are first class objects, metaclasses are, *bytecode* is a first class object (see `some_function.__code__`) etc.
Also in python there is no difference between closure and function. You can define functions everywhere you want. anonymous functions is a synonym for `lambda`s.

Comment: Thank you I understand better now